# MySQL : extract rows having 2 different values in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns looking like this :

| id | key | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | a |
| 3 | 3 | a |
| 4 | 1 | b |
| 5 | 2 | b |
| 6 | 4 | b |

I want to extract rows where a key have a "a" AND a "b" as status...

| id | key | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | a |
| 4 | 1 | b |
| 5 | 2 | b |

I KNOW that I need some GROUP BY and HAVING but I twisted my brain for few hours and I don't find any solution...

Thanx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use having count

```
select `key`
from my_table
where status in ('a','b')
group by `key`
having count(distinct status) =2;
```

If you need the other values you can use inner join with subquery

```
select m.*
from my_table m
inner join (select `key`
            from my_table
            where status in ('a','b')
            group by `key`
           having count(distinct status) =2
           ) tbl on m.`key`=tbl.`key`;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/yq5OiPtU

Comment: "where status in ('a','b')" was the trick I didn't think about  ! thanx